# How to make Web API Stop working on occurance of specific exception

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In some scenarios I am getting exceptions in Startup.cs file.
So I want to catch that exceptions and do not show specific errors to Users.

I tried this:

I catch exceptions and throw as Custom exceptions, even though it shows stack-trace and all things into browser.

And if I left catch block empty then Web API still remains **available (working).**

I want to pause or stop my service for this scenarios.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I've No rights to comment so I'm going to write my answer here
as far as I understood your question why don't you use `Application Error` in `global.asax` file
Just like this

```
 private void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

        if (ex is HttpAntiForgeryException)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Server.ClearError(); 
            Response.Redirect("/error/errorPage", true);
        }
    }
```

Hope I understood your question